# How to set priority for search value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a problem with setting priority for search value in my database. I would like to find all courses, which have a phrase (or contain word of the phrase) in the name course. 
Id addition, the course which have exactly the same name as searched phrase was in first place in the returned data.

Records for the **course** table:

```
+----+------+-------------------+
| id | code |        name       |
+----+------+-------------------+
| 1  | JPA  | JPA lorem ipsum   |
| 2  | JSF  | Jsf lorem ipsum   |
| 3  | HIB  | HIB lorem ipsum   |
| 4  | TEB  | TEB lorem ipsum   |
| 5  | ZRN  | Thanks in advance |
+----+------+-------------------+
```

## My query:

```
 SELECT `course`.`id`, `course`.`name` 
 FROM `course` 
 WHERE `name` LIKE 'TEB lorem ipsum' or 
       `name` LIKE '%TEB%' or 
       `name` LIKE '%lorem%' or 
       `name` LIKE '%ipsum%'
```

Database returns:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |      name       |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | JPA Lorem ipsum |
| 2  | Jsf Lorem ipsum |
| 3  | HIB Lorem ipsum |
| 4  | TEB lorem ipsum |
+----+-----------------+
```

I would like to receive:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |      name       |
+----+-----------------+
| 4  | TEB lorem ipsum |
| 1  | JPA Lorem ipsum |
| 2  | Jsf Lorem ipsum |
| 3  | HIB Lorem ipsum |
+----+-----------------+
```

Record, which have 4id is the most matching and is first place in the returned data. Question, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do the trick.

```
SELECT `course`.`id`, `course`.`name` 
 FROM `course` 
 WHERE `name` LIKE 'TEB lorem ipsum' or 
       `name` LIKE '%TEB%' or 
       `name` LIKE '%lorem%' or 
       `name` LIKE '%ipsum%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `name`='TEB lorem ipsum' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC
```

In short, it checks if name equals value and gives it a 1, else a 2. And then it orders it in a ascending order.

Comment: I think a simple IF should do the trick, not ? `IF(name = 'TEB lorem ipsum', 1, 2);`

Comment: Thank you very much guys! First and second solution is good and it works! Thanks!